# ping from another computer to second NIC

Tags: networking, ping, network-adapter

I have a pc that has two NIC:

1.ip: 192.168.55.5

2.ip: 182.19.45.103
(ip's are not real. That's for example)
also have a pc that connected to a network that can get ping from first ip(192.168.55.5) via vpn connection.

**Now I want get ping from second ip(182.19.45.103) but I can't**. I try bridge network between two NIC but when enable bridge mode, one of the NIC's ran out of ping access. and I try make first pc as VPN server but no result.

please help me!

Comment: I do not know how your VPN is set up, but commonly you would have access to the internal subnet range which you have.  182.19.45.103 is a Vodafone IP and it seems likely to me you would not be able to bridge back out from the internal address.  Also the external address you are trying to ping may not accept pings (common).

Comment: Yes - I checked. The address you are trying to ping does not accept pings.

Comment: Guess: From the box where you are doing the ping, you don't route to the second IP via the first ip's subnet. Assuming Linux, try `ip route get 182.19.45.103` from the box where you are doing the ping, and see if it goes through the interface that goes to `192.168.55.5`.